# C# method to return a type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, return-type

I have couple of classes that are identified by some ID (which is unique integer for every class). Next I need a method which takes an integer (ID) as argument and return corresponding class type. So far I have come to this:

```
public static Type GetById(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1: return (new ClassA()).GetType();
        case 2: return (new ClassB()).GetType();
        case 3: return (new ClassC()).GetType();
        // ... and so on
    }
}
```

For now it seems that it works, but for some reason I don't like that I have to instantiate the class to get its type. Could this cause any problems?

Another solution I found is to use Type.GetType(*classNameAsString*) method, but I guess this could cause some runtime errors or bugs in case class name is changed (i.e. I change the name of class, but forgot to update the GetById method).

Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: are you trying to make a factory?

Comment: Not really, I just need the type to supply it to generic method in underlying api.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`typeof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) operator instead

```
public static Type GetById(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 1: return typeof(ClassA);
        case 2: return typeof(ClassB);
        case 3: return typeof(ClassC);
        // ... and so on
    }
}
```

As a side note, I would seriously question this whole design - it feels weird to map types to integers.

Comment: Is it weird? Consider a configuration file when an enumeration with *N* values is used to specify a behaviour, and that behaviour is provided by *N* classes. You will want to map the enumeration value to those types.

Comment: @Gusdor I guess it's not that far-fetched after all. But still, that would map an enum to an *instance* of a type, not an integer to a `Type`.

Comment: Ah, I understand your reservation. It is odd after all!

Comment: Now I feel embarrassed because of my poor memory ommiting typeof... Thanks, I'll accept answer as soon as possible. About the design thing, I am also not so confident, but it is the easiest way to get things done without major refactoring.

Comment: @Gusdor: in a configuration file, why not just list the full type name? That's what .NET does.

Answer (score 13):

Why don't you just declare a *dictionary*?

```
  private static Dictionary<int, Type> types = new Dictionary<int, Type>() {
    {1, typeof(ClassA)},
    {2, typeof(ClassB)},
    {3, typeof(ClassC)},
    ... and so on
  };

  public static Type GetById(int id) {
    Type result = null;

    if (types.TryGetValue(id, out result))
      return result;

    return null; // or throw exception
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be creating an `enum`:

```
public enum ClassType
{
    ClassA = 1,
    ClassB = 2,
    ClassC = 3
}
```

And then changing your method to accept this `enum` and return the type:

```
public static Type GetById(ClassType id)
{
    //Will return null if the Type is not found, 
    //Add true as a second parameter to throw if not found
    return Type.GetType(id.ToString());
}
```

Doing so will remove magic numbers from your code, but will only work as long as your classes names match the enum options. This will make your code significantly smaller, but as pointed by others, you should really question your application design because this doesn't feel quite right.